# WCF service file not visible

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

We have an existing WCF service with multiple svc files.

Today, all of a sudden, one of the svc files no longer works:

- the page is not visible in IIS content view (although other svc files
  are)
- when navigating to the page, a 404 error is returned
- the file exists and is visible in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio
- on a different development machine everything works correctly

We have tried the following in our attempts to resolve the issue:

- successfully created and navigated to a different svc file - which leads us to believe IIS configuration is correct.
- removing and re-adding the page in question. did not work.
- rebooted the machine
- restarted IIS

Any ideas about what can be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the `applicationHost.config` file of IIS located here: `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`

As per [MSDN](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/introduction-to-applicationhostconfig):

> ApplicationHost.config is the root file of the configuration system
>   when you are using IIS 7 and above. It includes definitions of all
>   sites, applications, virtual directories and application pools, as
>   well as global defaults for the web server settings (similar to
>   machine.config and the root web.config for .NET Framework settings).

So once we opened up the file (your run-of-the-mill xml config file) we noticed that the path for the application was pointing directly to a svc file, rather than to a folder location. Like so:

```
<application path="/[APP NAME]" applicationPool="ASP.NET V4.0 Integrated">
  <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Projects\[FOLDER PATH]\[APP NAME]\Service.svc" />
</application>
```

Notice the `physicalPath` attribute (specifically `Service.svc`):

```
path="/" physicalPath="C:\Projects\[FOLDER PATH]\[APP NAME]\Service.svc"
```

This is what was causing the problem.

So all we had to do was remove the name of the service from the path and everything worked. Like so:

```
<application path="/[APP NAME]" applicationPool="ASP.NET V4.0 Integrated">
  <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Projects\[FOLDER PATH]\[APP NAME]" />
</application>
```